# Cannot create a business-pro account in sandbox?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am unsure if the sandbox developer site has a problem.

I tried to create a new pro account [mikev-facilitator-pro]. Even though it appears to save with a success message, the account does not appear in my list of accounts.

So then I decided to clone my existing business account [mikev-facilitator]. That worked, however, when accessing the profile of the new account [mikev-facilitator-pro] I get the following message.

```
We experienced some issues on our end while creating this Sandbox account. 
Please delete it and try again.
```

[image]

On trying to delete that account [mikev-facilitator-pro] I get the following message.

```
The following accounts you are trying to delete are designated owners of an app and 
cannot be deleted. Please delete the linked apps and try again.
[mikev-facilitator-pro]@example.com
```

[image]

I only have one app and that app is only linked to my [mikev-facilitator] account, not my [mikev-facilitator-pro] account.

[image]

[image]

(See, not mikev-facilitator-pro)

Comment: this happens probably because of when you were creating your business account, you clicked login with paypal enabled, This enabling process created a rest api but from your applications it can not be seem, so first you need to delete this rest api, i dont know how but i am pretty sure it was like that