# Able to set Tax calculation during PayPal express in SandBox?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

How can I setup my PayPal sandbox account with tax settings?

I would like to setup tax as per the tax at the bottom of this page.
https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=xpt/Marketing/shipping/EasyCalculateShipAndTax-outside%20

I do not see these options in PayPal developer sandbox site setup.

*What I would like to happen is PayPal works out that the billing address for the purchaser is in Australia, add 10% GST and then on the response, notifies me that 10% gst was applied (or the amount of other ways) so I can record that against the order and show it on the receipt.*

Is paypal pro account needed? If so, I am also having problems making a pro account as outlined in this SO Question:
[Cannot create a business-pro account in sandbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26624343/cannot-create-a-business-pro-account-in-sandbox)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shipping calculator in PayPal website applies **only** to Website Payment Standard Buttons(Buy now, add to cart etc). If you would like to pass tax in PayPal Express Checkout, you need to pass tax using API [variables](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/) such as `PAYMENTREQUEST_n_TAXAMT`. You don't need PRO account to do this.

Comment: I know I can pass Tax. I don't know if the buyer has to pay tax because I don't know if they live in Australia or not until after they have completed the paypal process. The payment object has already been created and sent to paypal and all that is left is to confirm the payment on the returnurl page. Its not like they get to the returnurl page and I go, oh, you live in Australia, btw, you need to pay 10% more now.